# Timepicker not displaying

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I'm using [jQuery simple timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) (just the timepicker not the datetimepicker) and I can't get it to show. I'm using modx 1.0.6 evolution and adding the timepicker to a opt-in form via a chunk.

here's the opt-in form code:

```
<div><input type="text" name="basic_example_2" id="basic_example_2" value="" /></div>
```

Here's my page header, I have revised that all the jQuery files are where the are supposed to be and also checked the jQuery code with JSlint and it says it's ok:

```
<head>
<title>[(site_name)] | [*pagetitle*]</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=[(modx_charset)]" />
<base href="[(site_url)]"></base>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/landing-page/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/landing-page/modxmenu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/landing-page/form.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/landing-page/modx.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/landing-page/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="[(site_url)][~11~]" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css"    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="assets/templates/landing-page/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
<script src="manager/media/script/mootools/mootools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/templates/modxhost/drop_down_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/templates/landing-page/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/templates/landing-page/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({showAnim: 'slideDown'});
    });
</script>
<script>
    $('#basic_example_2').timepicker();
</script>
</head>
```

I have tried this:

```
$('#basic_example_2').timepicker({});
```

and this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#basic_example_2').timepicker({});
});
```

and this:

```
$('#basic_example_2').timepicker();
```

And just in case it matters which I don't think it should but hey the CSS has been added to my layout.css file:

```
.ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dt { height: 25px; margin-bottom: -25px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 65px; }
.ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
.ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl{ direction: rtl; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl { text-align: right; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl dd { margin: 0 65px 10px 10px; }
```

Comment: Your timepicker should definitely be inside a document.ready. Also, IDs have to be unique, so make sure you don't have #basic_example_2 on the page more than once.

Comment: And are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: First of thanks for the speedy responses I've lurked on this site for years and never posted....
no errors in the console I'm using chrome canary and it's not throwing anything up, I've tried different id's as well this is just exactly as it's shown on his site, i've even downloaded his entire site and have it working locally here but can't get it working on this modx instal!!!!!!!! :(
When you you say it should be in a document.ready. what exactly do you mean?
Thanks again 
Chris

Comment: Have you checked if any modx plugins are loading old versions of JQuery? This link says that a plugin called QuickManager may conflict with the JQuery above: http://forums.modx.com/thread/77168/jquery-conflict-while-logged-in

Comment: thanks for the advice mccannf I just tried it and to no avail!!!

Comment: I Fixed this myself thanks for all the help anyway, i added the JS to the chunk instead of the head of the template sodding MODX was stripping it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the JS files from the chunk as modx seems to strip them when in the chunks and added them directly between the  tags. hope this helps some one else.